# Why do form-groups have a negative margin in Bootstrap?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have this very simple code using Bootstrap 3:

```
<html>
  <body>
    <main class="container" role="main">
      <form class="simple_form form-horizontal">
         <div class="form-group text required campaign_url">
           <label class="text required control-label" for="campaign_url"><abbr title="required">*</abbr> Url</label>
           <textarea class="text required form-control" name="campaign[url]" id="campaign_url"></textarea>
         </div>
```

and it appears like this:

[image]

Notice how tho labels and the inputs are sticking to the left. Inspecting those elements I found this:

```
.form-horizontal .form-group {
  margin-left: -15px;
  margin-right: -15px;
}
```

Why is that there? I know it's trivial to remove, but it makes me wonder whether the way I'm using Bootstrap is wrong. How should I use it?

Comment: They're meant to be used inside of `.row .col-*`. Pretty much all content in a bootstrap site should be in some `.col-*` div, wrapped with a `.row` div inside the `.container` div.

Comment: They?  What exactly are you referring to?  The form groups?  So the structure is .form-horizontal > .col-* > .form-group > .control?  What is a form group and what is it grouping?  A single control and its label?  A bunch of related controls like a set of radio buttons?

Answer (score 16):

It's happening because you are using `form-horizontal` which is meant to be used as a row along with `col-*`'s for layout. From the Bootstrap docs:

> Use Bootstrap's predefined grid classes to align labels and groups of form controls in a horizontal layout by adding .form-horizontal to the form (which doesn't have to be a `<form>`). Doing so changes `.form-groups` to behave as grid rows, so no need for `.row`.

So if you simply remove the `form-horizontal` the negative margin goes away.

http://codeply.com/go/QQnqgfKv9v

Comment: So when using .form-horizontal... does that mean you're supposed to be adding col-* to individual input and label controls within the .form-group?  You said "form-horizontal... is meant to be used as a row", but then you said "by adding .form-horizontal to the form... doing so change .form-groups to behave as grid rows".  So which is it? Is the form supposed to be a row or is the form-group supposed to be a row?  That has impliciations as to where you're supposed to put the col-* classes, either on the .form-group or on controls in the group.  Very confusing and convoluted.

Answer (score 0):

I just spend some time getting to understand this negative margin as well.
Turns out that normally you embed a form-horizontal into a container or container-fluid that puts a margin of 15px and the form-groups use -15px.

The real problem is that you are missing some `<div class="col-...">` to wrap your label and form controls.

These add some padding left+right and that will display it correctly.

Something like:

```
<html>
  <body>
    <main class="container" role="main">
      <form class="simple_form form-horizontal">
        <div class="form-group text required campaign_url">
          <div class="col-md-12">
            <label class="text required control-label" for="campaign_url"><abbr title="required">*</abbr> Url</label>
          </div>
          <div class="col-md-12">
            <textarea class="text required form-control col-md-12" name="campaign[url]" id="campaign_url"></textarea>
          </div>
        </div>
```